# Classification of analytic involutions

Tags: functions, analytic-functions, involutions

Does there exist a classification of all analytic involutions? I only know $x\mapsto x$, $x\mapsto -x$, $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$, and "shifts" thereof.